# Testing sensors?

Tags: sensor, best-practice

In industry, when purchasing sensors from an external manufacturers, are those sensors tested, and if so, how thoroughly? For example, I buy some accelerometers from Sparkfun and do some minimal testing using gravity. Is this a waste of time? What are the chances of getting a defective sensor?

Answer (score 2):

The chances of a bad sensor (if you're buying 1-10 units) is probably acceptably low.  I think you'll notice if you do any testing of your device when the sensor is installed.  But a dedicated method for testing just the sensor might be a little onerous.

Answer (score 2):

Many accelerometers have internal test hardware, which apply known forces electrostatically to the sensing element- this would be what manufacturers use for production test. You would not normally expect any device like this to be faulty on arrival - a significant part of the price you pay for any semiconductor device is testing.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the manufacturers quality standards. Some more expensive components/chips are 100% tested. Some cheaper devices are tested through sampling, 1 to 10, 1 to 1000. In this case they try to sample at least one unity from each package.

You should also consider storage and transportation. Accelerometers can be more sensitive to vibration than other circuits.

You can find the ratio of defective/working items/sensors from the history of that specific vendor/manufacturer. This is done in bigger manufacturers when planning new products or building costs.

So, if the quantity is low, I'd advice you to test all of them. Extra care is never enough, nothing is worst then build the whole board and try to find the defective component.